# TeamCity API to get list of most often failing tests

Tags: api, rest, teamcity

We have a suite of UI tests and some of them randomly fail only on TeamCity.

How do I get through REST API (or any other way!) the list of most often failing tests, so do I know how to set priorities on investigations.

I've started trying to get a simple lists of tests for a project, but it fails with `BadRequest`

```
/app/rest/testOccurrences?build:(project:(id:My_Tests_Prj))
```

The API to get currently failing `/app/rest/testOccurrences?locator=currentlyFailing:true` is not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the core problem. Although it's not from `REST API`, it does the job.

Since the version 7.x, when you navigate to a project page, there is a tab `Current problems`. And on this tab there is a link on the right-top corner (not quite obvious) `View tests failed within the last 120 hours`.

I learned that in the newest 2020 version there is a change and flaky tests are exposed in a better way.